# SharePoint calendar - setting regional time

Tags: calendar, regional-settings

I have a site collection for reserving resources (conference rooms, equipment, vehicles, etc.). I also have users that are in various time zone. The farm is setup to central time zone. It messes up calendar entry for someone in pacific time or eastern time when they have to put in a calendar entry for dr appointment or so forth. you get the point. there is a setting for time but it's at the site collection level which will not work. is there a way to recognize user's regional setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each user can set their time zone in their profile (or you can set it directly via User Profile services).

Open up the profile, switch to Language and Region settings and update the timezone.  Now when they interact with the Calendars they show the appropriate times.

EDIT

They may have to change a setting to say to use their regional settings vs. admin specified before they can change the time zone.
[image]